# What is better: function or define

Tags: c, function, optimization, c-preprocessor

I have couple of simple functions like

```
#define JacobiLog(x1,x2) ((x1>x2)?x1:x2)+log(1+exp(-fabs(x1-x2)))
```

What is better to implement (code, compile, memory...) - as above with define or to write some simple function

```
double JacobiLog(double x1,double x2)
{
     return ((x1>x2) ? x1 : x2) + log(1+exp(-fabs(x1-x2)));
}
```

Comment: Function return can create another copy of the returned variable. May be slower. Maybe usage of & can get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will probably automatically set your function as **inline**. You should use it and not a define.

It will also avoid unexpected comportment in the case where you use your define as

```
double num = JacobiLog(x++, y++);
```

I let you imagine the problem with code replacement...

Answer (score 0):

`define` can *possibly* be little faster, but most probably compiler will inline the function anyway (or you can mark as inline) and they will be the same. But function is better, because it is more readable and easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The function is *better*, assuming a good compiler.

With the function, it is left to the compiler whether the code is inlined, or not (assuming the definition of the function is accessible to everyone who uses it, for example if it is an `inline` function declared in a header for C++, or just a plain function with all of its users in the same translation unit). With the macro, it is always inlined, which is not necessarily faster, as it may lead to code bloat and therefore more cache misses and page faults.

Not to mention macros are difficult to read and, even worse, to debug.

Comment: "better" is a bit vague and it doesn't in general depend on the compiler since we're talking about a micro-optimization. `inline`, as far as I recall, is just a compiler hint. The compiler is free to ignore it or inline any non-`inline` function, subject to inline-ability.

Comment: I mention `inline` because it is required to have the function defined in a header without violating ODR, not because it affected the compiler's ability to inline code. It does not, it is indeed just a hint.

Because `better` is vague, I put it in italics.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the 'define' is faster (since it prevents a function call), the compiler can optimize and inline your function, and make it as fast.

If you are in a c++ environment, you should always use template and functions. It will make you're program more readable and prevent type error.

In C, macro can be useful since the type is not specified (see example below):

```
/* Will work with int, long, double, short, etc. */
#HIGHER(VAL1, VAL2)  ((VAL1) > (VAL2) ? (VAL1) : (VAL2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a micro-optimization. Unless you're doing embedded programming and every instruction counts, go with the function. Not to mention that the `log` is likely about 100x slower than the overhead to call a function. So you can only get about a 1% saving if your program consists mainly of calling this function. **<sup>[1]</sup>** Once your program starts doing significant other things, this saving will be reduced to basically unnoticeable.

The compiler is free to inline the function wherever possible, which would make the two identical. However, you can't force the compiler to do so. There is an `inline` keyword in C++, but this is just a hint, the compiler is free to ignore it.

See [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-and-perf.html) for some differences between the two (this covers inline versus non-inline functions, but, as stated above, inline functions are essentially the same as `#define`'s). The basic conclusion to the link is "it depends".

Also note that, behaviourally, [a `#define` and a function are not 100% equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614406/1711796).

[1]: Figures largely made up. Benchmark if you want accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

First (for a complete answer) we have to acknowledge that using a macro can have surprise side-effects which you might not intend, and that a function ensures that you know the incoming types and you know that each parameter is evaluated exactly once.

More often than not, these effects of using a macro are a source of problems.

Generally a compiler will inline the function as appropriate, and if it does its job right then it should have nearly all the advantages of a macro but without the rarely-intended side-effects.

Occasionally, though, you can actually get some benefits that an inlining compiler mightn't recognise.  For example your macro will temporarily defer converting the arguments to `double` if they were `int` or `long` and perform more operations in integer arithmetic (which might have a performance or precision advantage).  You might also get integer overflow and incorrect results.

Since you included 'memory' in your list of "better" factors, it's tempting to say that the function is smaller (assuming you configure your compiler to optimise for size), but this isn't necessarily true.

Obviously as a function you need only one copy of it in memory and all callers can use that same code, whereas inlined or expanded at every use duplicates the code.  Your compiler is very unlikely to isolate a macro and convert it into a function called from many different places in the code.

Where a never-inlined function can fail to be smaller is where it stands in the way of simplifications.  There are three common cases I can think of:

1. If all of the uses of the function involve constant parameters, the inlined simplifications might come out smaller than the whole original function.
2. The register marshalling code required to execute a function call with the parameters in the correct registers can be longer than the function itself.
3. Adding a function call can add to the register pressure in the caller, forcing it to generate more complicated code, possibly forcing it to create a stack frame and save more registers on entry and exit.